# Android ContentProviders vs SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

If we want to share our data with other Android applications,

(1) we may create a SQlite database and make it accessible by other applications or

(2) create a ContentProvider.

What are the basic differences in the above mentioned two approaches?

Comment: They aren't exclusive.  You can have a content provider backed.by a SQLite db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentProvider is exposing data to other application, a non-content provider database is only accessible by that application.

Comment: But when we create a SQLite db we can specify the access mode as public, what that exactly mean?

Comment: Dunno where you got this information but you're wrong.. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Comment: Indeed.  JonTraex has it right.  You can make a content provider public that accesses the SQLite db, but you cannot make the db itself available to anything other than your app.